# Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: java, android

I am getting strange issue while installing app. If i install app on Android 5.0 version and above then app is getting installed and working fine. But if i install app on lower version like 4.4 or 4.2 then its give me this error while installation.
[Getting error while installing app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a4c2.png)

After lots of RND i get that if your package name contains caps letters then you get this type of error but in my package name there is no cap letter. Below is my Manifest file code :-`
    package="com.aznimo">

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
////////////////
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="Comman.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash_Screen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login_Screen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login__screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Signup_Screen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signup__screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Forgot_Password"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot__password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider922739857843448"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Privacy_Policy_Screen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_privacy__policy__screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Home_Screen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home__screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Product_View_All"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Category_List_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Product_detail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".GalleryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".You_Tube_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Profile_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Edit_Profile_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="t4jsample"
                android:scheme="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".New_Address_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Twitter_Webview_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Address_List_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Order_List_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Order_Detail_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Search_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Cart_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Delivery_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Payment_Confirmation_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Payment_Method_Screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".New_Address_Screen_Map"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    /////////////
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.aznimo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".PushNotificationService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!--
      Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
      dispatching on non-Google Play devices
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <!--
         Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
         installation campaign reporting
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


</application>
```

`

I am not even getting any error in logcat section. Can any body tell me whats the problem or what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to press "ok"?

Comment: Your manifest tag is there is missing just in the above code only (not in actual file), right? Also, if in Studio pres Atl + Ctrl + L to reformat code, should help in readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this causes a "manifest malformed" error:

```
<application
    android:name="Comman.MyApplication"
```

If the application class name contains a `.`, it is treated as a fully qualified package name. The package part must start with a lowercase letter between `a` and `z` and yours begins with a capital `C`.

See the [`PackageParser` source](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java) for the various ways installation can fail with "manifest malformed". In this case `null` get returned from [`buildClassName()`](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java#buildClassName) when parsing the `application` element.